# Is this valid syntax for constraining nested tuples within a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I've got something like this snippet for something I'm working on:

$$
S = \lbrace (a, (b_0, \dots, b_n), c) : a \in A, \lbrace b_0, \dots, b_n \rbrace \subseteq B, c \in C, n \in {\mathbb N} \rbrace
$$

My goal here is to specify in the set constraint that the tuple $(b_0, \dots, b_n)$'s elements should all be members of set B, even though the tuple itself could contain duplicates. Is this even valid, and is there a better way to express this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not including when the b's are not unique.
S = $\cup${ A × $B^n$× C : n in N } includes nonunique b's.

Comment: Hm? Yes it is. ${1,2,1}\subseteq{1,2,3}$. And the $n\in N$ should be below the $\bigcup$ at the beginning: otherwise, if you write $\cup X$, you mean $\bigcup_{S\in X} S$, which is a *very* different thing.

Comment: What does "1,2,1 subset 1,2,3" mean quibbling @Deusovi?

Comment: ...It means I forgot to escape my braces. My bad. Should've been $\{1,2,1\}\subseteq\{1,2,3\}$. The point was that his original notation seems to me to allow some of the $b_i$s to be equal, since sets *can* be written with repeated elements - they're just the same as if those elements weren't repeated.

Comment: It did not @Deusovi.  As {1,2,1} has only two elements, it is rendered (1,2) and not (1,2,1).

Comment: That is *one* way to write the set {1,2}, but it is not the only way. {1,2,1} is just as valid of an expression, no? It's not *used* as often, sure, but it is equally valid.

Comment: @Deusovi.  No, it's stuttering.